# Clearing Python Objects with no References from Memory

Tags: python, memory, tkinter

I've been working on a very simple game in Python using Tkinter, just to see if I could.  There's a List which holds all the game objects, and every tick of the main loop the List is cycled through and each object in the List draws itself to the window.

Whenever the user fires a laser, a new laser object is dynamically added to the List without assigning it to a variable.  In simplified form, it's like this:

```
if buttonIsPressed:
    game.itemlist.append(LaserObject())
```

When the laser draws itself it tests its position in the window and when it gets to a certain point, it removes itself from the List and is no longer drawn.  It has no other references, but it seems to be staying in memory anyhow.

While firing the laser, and therefore creating more laser objects, the memory usage of the program goes up and up.  As a test, I did that until the memory usage got to 10MB, then I let the program just sit there for an hour to see if any of those laser objects with no references would get garbage collected and the memory usage of the program would go back down, but it never did.  It stayed right at 10 MB.

In this circumstance, is there something else I need to do to get those laser objects to be garbage collected properly so they won't keep taking up memory and the overall memory usage of the program can stay steady?

Comment: My tkinter knowledge is a bit rusty, but I think we need to see the code that creates the laser objects.

Comment: Try calling `gc.collect()` and then check the contents of `gc.garbage`. It may be that LaserObject is creating an internal object that can't be freed for some reason. If there are LaserObject in the garbage list then are you defining a `__del__` method or subclassing a class that has one?

Comment: I don't think the Python interpreter ever gives memory back to the operating system even when objects are deleted and unused objects have been garbage-collected. This means that the memory footprint of the process will never get smaller.

Comment: 10 MB of memory is not that bad. I'd assume that the Python GC collector is "lazy" and only releases memory when needed. As long as your computer does not start to swap memory to HDD, this is not a problem.

Comment: I wasn't so concerned with how much memory the program was using per se', I was more concerned with the fact that memory usage continued to go up and up whenever lasers were being used.  It turns out that a Label inside the LaserObject class was getting stuck in memory so I've added an answer describing my solution.  Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem had to do with a Label not being removed from memory.

Originally each LaserObject had a Label inside it which the laser image was drawn onto.  Later I switched to drawing the image on the canvas directly, but the Label object remained inside LaserObject and wasn't getting deleted properly.

When I removed the Label entirely from LaserObject the image started to flicker like crazy on the canvas, probably having to do with the Label retaining a reference to the image therefore helping it to not get garbage collected too early or something like that.

The best solution for this situation was to allow the Label to remain in LaserObject, but add code to destroy the Label when the LaserObject was removed from the item list.  Like this:

```
if laser.y == past_edge_of_window:
    self.game.itemlist.remove(laser)
    self.label.destroy()
```

This tells Tk to clean up all the internal code for that Label object, and it keeps memory usage steady.